# Quickest ways to selectively sync iTunes artists (and ideally playlists) to Android?

Tags: itunes

What are the quickest ways to selectively sync iTunes artists (and ideally playlists) to Android? Has anyone designed any software that provides a quick and semi-automatic interface to do this, other than https://www.doubletwist.com/desktop ? Or is that the best option?

Comment: While this isn't a place for recommending software, you could use Winamp to filter your collection by Artist, transcode all of the artist's music to the format you need (I use m4a), then manually drag and drop the transcoded music into the device's music folder. WInamp does work with your iTunes collection.

Comment: Thanks - hardly as smooth a selective sync as iTunes offers though, so I'm still searching!